# How to connect to my own WiFi using Broadcom STA drivers?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom, asus

I'm trying hard to switch to Linux from Windows because of my engineering project. Unfortunately, everything is against that change!

1. Before I have installed Broadcom STA proprietary drivers, I was seeing on NetworkManager and nm-applet only local radio-internet-access networks.
2. After I installed Broadcom STA, I see my neighbor's wireless network (channel 11, WEP)
3. Neither before nor after the installation is own wireless network available.

Computer: Asus Lamborghini VX6
Ubuntu: 12.04 LTS 64-bit
Router: ASUS N55U (A1) with newest AsusWRT firmware
Network: Channel 5 (tried also 10 and 11, both on 20 and 40MHz bands), WPA2 Personal, 2,4 + 5 GHz (what is not very important, 'cause the wlan card in VX6 is only 2,4GHz).

Network works fine on Windows, also through D-Link repeater on the other floor. Unfortunately, same network is invisible to Ubuntu on same machine.

I have tried some combinations with other GUIs but it did not work. Are there any better drivers for Ubuntu?

I need that network badly, but I'm an Ubuntu newbie, so I don't know how to solve that problem. Please help.

Comment: If there are a number of wireless networks, there might be an entry - last in the list - with an arrow to show "More Networks."  If so, you might find your own network there (I sometimes find mine there, too).

Comment: Did you try the networkmanager selection "Connect to hidden network"? and enter your essid and key?  After the first time, you should connect automaticaly -- if not, in network manager, edit connections, and select your and add "connect automatically".

Comment: Yep, I've tried to force that network. Didn't work. Asks for authentication every 2 minutes of trying to connect.

The joke is, that the SSID isn't hidden :P

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Linux sux at wireless drivers, 'cause a lot of them has a limit of 11 channels out of 13 available. Moreover, even the network working in 40MHz mode, is ivisible, untill the first channel is under 5. 20MHz mode works from channel 1 to 11.

What's more amazing, is that my network, working on channel 5 now is recognised by Ubuntu as channel 7...

Question to drivers programmers and all that stuff: are you insane to make it different than in router that works on same type of kernel and is fully compatibile with e.g. Windows? -.-

Comment: Ta muchly, was having the same problem!