# BCM4313 Wireless on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: wireless, server, broadcom

I'm trying to run an old netbook with Broadcom BCM4313 wireless as a print server with Ubuntu Server 12.04. Setting up the wireless without the GUI, however, is proving problematic. I do think however I've narrowed down the problem.

I've tried both the `wl` driver (from `bcmwl-kernel-source`) as well as the (included) `brcmsmac` driver. With both of them, when I issue the command `iwlist wlan0 scanning` (`eth1` for `wl`), I only see neighbouring networks- not my own.

I believe this might be because my networks are n-only, but my neighbouring networks are mixed mode (I suspect this because the output of `iwlist wlan0 scanning` shows "Bit Rates" only as high as 54 Mb/s).

Any ideas how to go about getting this thing to connect?

Comment: Hi, my BCM4313 had the same problem last week. Turns out it doesn't pick up any networks on channels 12+. I lowered the network to channel 5 and now she's working.

Comment: I just saw that post actually- you're right! Many thanks. I'll go upvote your other post...

Comment: Actually, the post I'm referring to isn't yours:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/202689/how-to-connect-to-my-own-wifi-using-broadcom-sta-drivers

Comment: how did you even get any result with the `wl` driver for BCM4313? mine says `eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning.`

Comment: I'm not sure, it was a while ago :/ I installed it somehow from the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard me, I'm stupid. The very next thing I looked up on this site claimed that it doesn't support channels > 11, and my wlan was on ch13! Changing this to 11, connection worked a charm with the `wl` driver, like so:

`wpa_passphrase mySSID myPSK >> /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

`iwconfig eth1 essid mySSID`

`wpa_supplicant -D wext -i eth1 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

`dhclient eth1`

Comment: Glad you came right! Remember to mark the question as answered if all's well :)

Comment: Can't do it for two days... I'll try and remember!

Answer (score 2):

Set your network to mix mode, should fix it up. I had the same problem.