# Issue Connecting Wirelessly in Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, server

My mom just got a new computer and was going to throw her old one away since it's so old she won't get anything for it. So, I felt like giving myself a little project, and decided to make a server out of the old box. The installation went well except for one part; the part where it configured the network. I connected a USB wireless adapter, and told it to install without network configuration. Figured I could just configure it later. Guess I was wrong.

I did everything I thought I should do:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK-NAME key s:NETWORK-KEY
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

Everything worked until I did the `dhclient`. It just hangs there until until I manually stop it.

What can/should I do?

Comment: s:NETWORK-KEY implies that your network is encrypted with WEP using an ASCII string password. Is it? Is Network Manager installed on the system?

Comment: Sorry, still new to Ubuntu Server. I don't know if Network Manager is installed. I did, however, find a solution earlier this morning; http://askubuntu.com/questions/207607/bcm4313-wireless-on-ubuntu-server-12-04 Thank you for the reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone reads this,is having the same issue, and is looking for a solution. I found this, and it worked for me: [BCM4313 Wireless on Ubuntu Server 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207607/bcm4313-wireless-on-ubuntu-server-12-04)

I just changed everything where it says `eth1` to `wlan0`.

Comment: Glad it's sorted.